# Convert CSV with escaped comma

Tags: powershell

I have CSV data that may contain a comma in a data column. This comma is escaped:

```
A,B,C
1,2,a
2,3,\,
3,4, 
4,5,b
```

I want to read the CSV and concatenate all data in column **C** to single string. The result should be `a, b`. Please note the space from the line `3,4,` .

I would like to use ConvertFrom-Csv to read convert this data:

```
$in = @"
A,B,C
1,2,a
2,3,\,
3,4, 
4,5,b
"@

$in | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

But the function doesn't know about the escaped comma and puts the backslash in the data field.

How can I instruct that cmdlet to accept that `\,` shall be treated as a comma?

Comment: You may have to enclose the escaped comma in quotes first. AFAIK the CSV standard does not provide such a functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the delimiter with a delimiter that does not occur in the input, e.g.:

```
@"
A,B,C
1,2,a
2,3,\,
3,4,
4,5,b
"@.replace(',',';').replace('\;', ',') | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
```

Output:

```
A B C
- - -
1 2 a
2 3 ,
3 4
4 5 b
```

Comment: Probably noteworthy:  I first tried `-replace` instead of `.replace` without success. But your syntax gives success.

Comment: @harper: this works here `... -replace ',',';' -replace '\\;', ',' | ...`